# Syntax error thrown on prod server (Azure), but not locally - can't work out why

Tags: javascript, html, azure

Let me preface this by saying that I know this is extremely likey to be a standard basic syntax error in the script, but for the life of me I can't locate it.

This is the error getting thrown in the chrome inspection console -

```
community-details:481 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:8
    at Function.globalEval (jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:8)
    at jQuery.fn.init.domManip (jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:9)
    at jQuery.fn.init.append (jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:9)
    at jQuery.fn.init.<anonymous> (jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:9)
    at Function.access (jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:8)
    at jQuery.fn.init.html (jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:9)
    at Object.success (eval at <anonymous> (jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:8), <anonymous>:111:40)
    at c (jsbundle?v=hZeIDp2ez9Xzj2b2pzhcILhAY4fxF_YgY7wSOowNqpk1:8)
```

Although the error isn't in the stated file (community-details), when inspecting the source code, its located in a JS file, ive marked up what appears to be throwing the syntax error near the end of the function -

```
$('.move-new-to-group').on('click', function () {
        $('.page').attr("data-save", "Moving to group ...");
        $('.page').addClass("modal-save");
        $('.move-new-to-group').prop('disabled', true);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckCreateMembers","Member")',
           data:{
               "CommunityId": '@Model.CommunityId',
               "__RequestVerificationToken": $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(),
               "headers": headerList(),
               "lines": lineList(),
            },
            success: function (result) {

                console.log(result);
                if (result.ResultCode == 400) {
                    // Data was probably missing
                    $('.move-new-to-group').prop('disabled', false);
                }
                else {
                    if (result.Message.ExtraData.length > 0) {
                        var issueResponse = JSON.parse(result.Message.ExtraData);
                        if (issueResponse.HasErrors == true) {
                            var message = "";
                            if (issueResponse.NumErroredMessages == 1) {
                                message = "There was <b>1</b> entry with errors. Please fix it, then retry";
                            } else {
                                message = "There were <b>" + issueResponse.NumErroredMessages + "</b> entries with errors. Please resolve them, then retry";
                            }
                            message = message + "<br/>";
                            var errorsDict = new Object();
                            var problemRows = [];
                            issueResponse.Messages.forEach(x => x.HasErrors == true ? problemRows.push(x.RowNum) : '');
                            for (var i = 0; i < issueResponse.Messages.length; i++) {
                                var jsonMessage = issueResponse.Messages[i];
                                if (jsonMessage.RowNum == null) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                for (var k = 0; k < jsonMessage.Issues.length; k++) {
                                    var jsonIssue = jsonMessage.Issues[k]
                                    if (jsonIssue.IssueType == "Error") {
                                        var lineNum = 1;
                                        problemRows.forEach(x => x < jsonMessage.RowNum ? lineNum++ : lineNum += 0);
                                        if (errorsDict[jsonIssue.Message] == null) {
                                            errorsDict[jsonIssue.Message] = [/*jsonMessage.RowNum*/lineNum];
                                        } else {
                                            errorsDict[jsonIssue.Message].push(/*jsonMessage.RowNum*/lineNum);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            for (var key in errorsDict) {
                                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(errorsDict, key)) {
                                    var val = errorsDict[key];
                                    if (val.length == 1) {
                                        message = message + "<b>" +  key + "</b> on line<b>";
                                    } else {
                                        message = message + "<b>" +  key + "</b> on lines<b>";
                                    }
                                    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                                        if (i == 0) {
                                            message = message + " " + val[i];
                                        } else if (i < 30) {
                                            message = message + ", " + val[i];
                                        } else {
                                            message = message + "...";
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    message = message + "</b><br/>";
                                }
                            }
                            $('.message').html(message);
                        } else {
                            $('.message').html("");
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('.message').html("");
                    }
                    //$('.message').html(result.Message.ExtraData);
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.LineWasRead.length; i++) {
                        var status = result.LineWasRead[i];
                        if (status){
                            $($(".table-line")[i]).addClass('remove');
                        }
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.ReadUsers.length; i++) {
                        var user = result.ReadUsers[i];
                        $('.group-booking-group').append(memberDiv(user.Id, user.Name));
                        $('#group-change').append("<option value='.newmembers'>New members</option>");
                        $('#group-change').show();
                    }
                    countGroup();

                    $(".table-line.remove").each(function () {
                        moveAnimate(this, $('.group-booking-group-container'), $('.group-booking-group-container'),true);
                    });

                    //$(".line.remove").remove();
                    $(".table-line").addClass("error-flash");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                          $('.table-line').removeClass('error-flash');
                    }, 500);
                }
                $('.page').removeClass("modal-save");
            }, ***//<< this is what Chrome is locating as the error.***
            error: function (result) {
                console.log("ERROR");
                console.log(result);
                $('.move-new-to-group').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.page').removeClass("modal-save");
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('.move-new-to-group').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.page').removeClass("modal-save");
            }
        });
        console.log(headerList());
        console.log(lineList());
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you upload your files? Is there any non-printable characters in that file? Are line feeds correct? Maybe on server you have minified version and some content are commented?

Comment: Minification may sometimes produce syntactically incorrect output. Check if the problem goes away if you disable it. If so, try updating the Minification library to a newer version, or perhaps even try replacing it with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks both, found the issue!

Comment: @MattFuller You can post an answer to end this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Justinas and @Peter B 's comment. Post an answer to end this question:

> Minification may sometimes produce syntactically incorrect output. Check if the problem goes away if you disable it. If so, try updating the Minification library to a newer version, or perhaps even try replacing it with an alternative.